# Should I use a hardware wallet?

Tags: privacy, security, hardware-wallet

I hear a lot about hardware wallets and I would like to know if, in terms of security and functionality, it makes sense to switch to one of them.

Thanks in advance for answers.

Comment: Switch *from* what? Hot software wallet or cold software wallet?

Comment: Keep in mind your coins are always on the blockchain, not in a hardware wallet.  Hardware wallets hold keys, not coins.

Comment: @Dave, no cryptocurrency wallet holds "coins", regardless if of the hardware variety or not. cialu never made that assumption in the question in any case.

Comment: @TEV both kinds of wallet.

Answer (score 1):

In it's simplest form, a hardware wallet is for holding your private keys on a non-internet connected device. It is also designed to be easy to use *with* your internet connected machine whereby it can sign transactions without you having to transfer keys to your regular internet connected computer.

Should you switch is entirely personal choice and threat profile. There are alternative ways to achieve what's outlined above, such as using a computer that is never connected to the internet for holding your keys and signing transactions on that machine then transferring the signed tx to your regular internet connected machine for broadcasting.

Another option is to use multiple wallets, one with small holdings on your regular computer for daily use and another being a paper wallet for larger longer-term larger holdings.